# How do I auto tabulate the Column in B and C once I copy a Number that has been appeared before?

Tags: string, google-sheets, count, duplicates, tabulate

How do I auto tabulate the Column in B and C once I copy a Number that has been appeared previously?

=if(countif($A:$A,A6)>1, VLOOKUP(A6,$A:$B,2,False),"") I tried using this but not all the time it works. some fields cannot publish. I have aligned them to the same text format but does not help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_uWN-CCeO1K16GkJKamSKKm1bUGOhFlVU3vlfHwxkY/edit?usp=sharing

Auto Tabulate when the same number is entered into the sheet.

Comment: What do you mean by `Auto Tabulate`? Which one is your desired output?

Comment: @Harun24hr My desire output is Column B and C. If a number is entered in column A and there is previous records, it will auto tabulate. If there no previous record, it will be empty.

Comment: How google-sheet will generate serial numbers? Or do you only want word `Auto Tabulate` to column B and C?

Comment: can someone help on this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How you will define text of column B and C? Any explanation?